# Google Maps API Heatmap - Functions not working correctly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, geojson, heatmap

I have been working with the Google Maps API to develop a Heatmap. The heatmap uses data imported from a GeoJSON file, stored locally, I did this using the documentation found [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data/). However, I have tried adding the functions from the documentation found [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) (i.e. Toggle Heatmap, Change Gradient etc.) and for some reason it doesn't work, the map itself is load with the imported GeoJSON data, but the functions do not seem to work. Could anyone point me in the right direction why the functions do not work? Please find below my HTML. For this example I'm using Google's stock GeoJSON data which is defined within the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
      #map {
    height: 100%;
  }

  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
     }
  #floating-panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="floating-panel">
  <button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Toggle Heatmap</button><br>
  <button onclick="changeGradient()">Change gradient</button><br>
  <button onclick="changeRadius()">Change radius</button><br>
  <button onclick="changeOpacity()">Change opacity</button><br>
  </div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: 6,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.378051, -3.435973),
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });


    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

  }

  function eqfeed_callback(results) {
    var heatmapData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
      var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1], coords[0]);
      heatmapData.push(latLng);
    }
    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: heatmapData,
      dissipating: true,
      map: map
    });
    function toggleHeatmap() {
    heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
  }

  function changeGradient() {
    var gradient = [
      'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
      'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
      'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
      'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
      'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
      'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
    ]
    heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
  }

  function changeRadius() {
    heatmap.set('radius', heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20);
  }

  function changeOpacity() {
    heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2);
  }
  }
</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

toggleHeatmap and other functions are not global, they are inside eqfeed_callback. Move them out of eqfeed_callback to make them global.

Comment: Could you please provide a working example of this? for some reason it just broke the map when I tried it, thanks!

Comment: sorry, I can only point out the js syntax problem, I could not understand the google map api usage logic. You may read more about google-map api docs.